# Thicker line prevent transformatio

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I created an implementation of the interface java.awt.geom.Shape. This contains a sequence of paths in terms of PathIterator to draw the shape of an AND gate.
Now I want to move this shape when i move the mouse pointer. This works excellent but when i want to increase the thickness of lines this stops working. If i dont change the thickness of pen this works well.
When i set the width of pen to 1 it works. But when i set it to 10 just a part of gate apears seemingly drawn from the point (0,0) thus translate does not affected.
Here is the Gate source:

```
package pashe;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Gate implements Shape {

    GPathIterator pathIterator;
    public Gate(){

        pathIterator = new GPathIterator();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point2D arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Rectangle2D arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(double arg0, double arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(double arg0, double arg1, double arg2, double arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new Rectangle(0,0,50,30);
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle2D getBounds2D() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (new Rectangle(0,0,50,30));
    }

    @Override
    public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform arg0) {
    return pathIterator;

    }

    @Override
    public PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform arg0, double arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pathIterator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean intersects(Rectangle2D arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean intersects(double arg0, double arg1, double arg2, double arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


}
```

```
package pashe;

import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;

public class GPathIterator implements PathIterator {

    int current = 0;
    @Override
    public int currentSegment(float[] points) {
        switch (current){
        case 0:{
            points[0] = 0;
            points[1] = 0;
            return PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO;
        }
        case 1:
        {
            points[0] = 15;
            points[1] = 0;
            return PathIterator.SEG_LINETO;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            points[0] = 40;
            points[1] = 0;
            points[2] = 40;
            points[3] = 15;
            return PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            points[0] = 40;
            points[1] = 30;
            points[2] = 15;
            points[3] = 30;
            return PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            points[0] = 0;
            points[1] = 30;
            return PathIterator.SEG_LINETO;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            return PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE;
        }


        default:
            return -1;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int currentSegment(double[] arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return current;
    }

    @Override
    public int getWindingRule() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isDone() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (current < 6)
        return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void next() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        current++;
    }

}
```

```
package pashe;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;
import java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

public class Prob extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    Adap adap;
    BasicStroke stroke;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Prob frame = new Prob();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Prob() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
                adap.mouseMoved(e);
            }
        });

        //System.out.println(stroke.getLineWidth());
        adap = new Adap(this);
        contentPane.addMouseListener(adap);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        /*super.paint(g);
        if (adap.evt != null){
        int x = adap.evt.getX();
        int y = adap.evt.getY();
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
        GeneralPath gp = new GeneralPath();
        gp.moveTo(x, y);
        gp.lineTo(x + 15 , y);
        gp.quadTo(x + 40, y , x + 40, y + 15);
        gp.quadTo(x + 40, y + 30, x + 15, y + 30);
        gp.lineTo(x, y+30);
        gp.closePath();
        g2d.draw(gp);
        gp.moveTo(x - 8, y + 5);
        gp.lineTo(x, y + 5);
        gp.moveTo(x - 8, y + 25);
        gp.lineTo(x, y + 25);
        g2d.draw(gp);
        gp.moveTo(x + 40, y + 15);
        gp.lineTo(x + 48, y + 15);
        g2d.draw(gp);
        }*/
        //g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        BasicStroke old = (BasicStroke)g2d.getStroke();
               stroke = new BasicStroke(10f,old.getEndCap(),old.getLineJoin(),old.getMiterLimit(),old.get    DashArray(),old.getDashPhase());

                if (adap.evt == null)
        {

            return;
        }
        super.paint(g);
        int x = adap.evt.getX();
        int y = adap.evt.getY();
                  System.out.println("x=" + x + " y=" + y);
        Shape shape = new Gate();
        AffineTransform trans =  AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x,y);

        //Shape shape = trans.createTransformedShape(gate);
        //shape = stroke.createStrokedShape(shape);
                //g2d.fill(shape);
        //Shape shape = trans.createTransformedShape(gate);
        //g2d.setTransform(trans);
                //shape = new Ellipse2D.Double(0,0,18,18);
        g2d.setStroke(stroke);
        g2d.transform(trans);
                //shape = trans.createTransformedShape(shape);
        g2d.draw(shape);
                g2d.setStroke(old);
    }

    class Adap extends MouseAdapter {
        Prob prob;
        MouseEvent evt;
        public Adap(Prob p){
            prob = p;
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent ev) {
            evt = ev;
            prob.repaint();
        }
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent ev) {
            evt = ev;
            prob.repaint();
        }


    }
    }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). The first thing you might do before combining the classes into a single source is to remove the 20 or so lines of commented code!

Comment: BTW - better to override `paintComponent(Graphics)` in a `JPanel` than `paint(Graphics)` in a `JFrame`..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following - read Graphics2D for more info:

```
    g2d.setStroke(stroke);
    g2d.transform(trans);
    Shape shape2 = stroke.createStrokedShape(shape);
    g2d.draw(shape2);
```

Good Work!